# Combining array with condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as below

```
arr1 = [{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '786'
}]
```

I want the resulting array where duplicates from array based on name is removed but if the ProjectId = 123 keep that in array and remove other duplicate

i.e in above example there are 2 duplicates with name Ken but one record has ProjectId  = 123 , in that case consider this record and delete other similar name duplicate

Also , if the duplicate does not contain ProjectId as 123 remove any one duplicate.
Ex : In above example there are 2 duplicates with name Kris but don't have ProjectId as 123 in that case consider any one of the record.

i.e my resulting array should be like this

```
[{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}]
```

or

```
[{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '786'
}]
```

Comment: What specific aspect of this are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Use an dictionary to record the name already checked before. If name exist & id != 123 then skip.

Comment: What if there are duplicates and none have the ID of 123?  You need to be more specific, and you also need to post your code and explain what went wrong with it (any errors etc.) so we can help fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
var arr1 = [{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '786'
}];

function filter(arr) {

    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i === j) { continue; }
            if (arr[j].Name === arr[i].Name) {
                var spliceIndex = (arr[j].ProjectId === '123') ? i : j;

                arr.splice(spliceIndex, 1);
                j--;

                if (spliceIndex === i) {
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

console.log(filter(arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicatesByName(arr) { 
    var obj = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         obj[arr[i].Name] = arr[i];
    }
    var out = [];
    for(var key in obj)
        out.push(obj[key]);
    out.sort(function(a, b){ return a.ProjectId - b.ProjectId; });
    return out;
}
```

This uses the fact that objects can't have duplicate keys to remove all the duplicates in your array by name. It returns them sorted by `ProjectId`, since the ordering will be lost when it goes into an object.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kzvtLov/3/)

This should work. :)

```
var arr1 = [{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '786'
}];

var removeDups = function (array) {
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj1 = array[i];
        for (var j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (j==i)
                continue;
            var obj2 = array[j];

            if (obj1.Name == obj2.Name) {
                var indexToDelete = checkProject123(i, j);
                array.splice(indexToDelete-1, indexToDelete);
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}

var checkProject123 = function (i, j) { 
    if (arr1[i].ProjectId == '123')
        return j; // Index i has projectId 123 so return j to be deleted.
    else if (arr1[j].ProjectId == '123')
        return i; // Index j has projectId 123 so return i to be deleted.
    else
        return i; // Neither of them have projectId 123 so delete the first one, idk
}

console.log(removeDups(arr1));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one solution. You can filter your input array and search if the current element position is the same that the first result in the input array to eliminate the duplicates.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '123'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ken',
    'ProjectId': '223'
}, {
    'Name': 'Ben',
    'ProjectId': '229'
}, {
    'Name': 'Alex',
    'ProjectId': '222'
}, {
    'Name': 'Kris',
    'ProjectId': '786'
}];

var result=arr1.filter(function(e,i,a){
  if (a.map(function(d) { return d['Name']; }).indexOf(e.Name) == i) {
    return e;
  }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use lodash's [uniq](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) function. Pass in a custom comparator. Example code from their documentation:

```
// using an iteratee function
_.uniq([1, 2.5, 1.5, 2], function(n) {
  return this.floor(n);
}, Math);
// → [1, 2.5]
```

Or the pluck shorthand:

```
// using the `_.property` callback shorthand
_.uniq([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
```

I believe underscore.js has the same function.

Comment: @Andy hmmm guess I can't actually understand the question. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯